Taking account of generator ramp constraints in pypsa optimisation
I would like to know how Pypsa handles the ramp constraints (on load, at start-up and at shutdown) of generators. Is it sufficient to fill in these attributes only or does it require additional codes?
I would also like to know if the optimisation programme is independent per snapshot or does Pypsa take into account the results of previous snapshots?
Thank you in advance for your feedback.
I've read the pypsa documentation but it's still not clear in my head.
